# Adding new record to database prevents echoing other records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forum

Hi i have created a forum website where logged in users can create topics using a form on each forum topic, however when I add a new record using the form it prevents itself and the previous topics from being displayed.

I have no idea why and would be greatful for any help.
I have my forum page which displays categories, topics(if category is selected) and replies (if topic is selected). Here is the code for my forum.php page

```
    <div id="midclmn">
    <?php

    If (isset($_GET['topic'])){

        // Show topic & replies

        $queryreply = "SELECT a.reply_id,a.reply_text, a.reply_date, b.topic_title, b.topic_date,c.username AS reply_user, (SELECT username FROM users 
        WHERE user_id=b.user_id) AS topic_creator FROM forum_replies a 
        LEFT JOIN forum_topics b ON a.topic_id=b.topic_id
        LEFT JOIN users c ON a.user_id=c.user_id

                WHERE a.topic_id = '".$_GET['topic']."'    ";
                       $result = mysql_query($queryreply) or die (mysql_error());
                        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                         if(empty($row['reply_id'])){
                        echo "No replies have been posted in this Topic, be the first to have your say using form below.";} ?>



        <table id="categorytable">

                <tr><td><?php echo '<b>'.$row['topic_title'].'</b>';?></b><br></td></tr>
                <tr><td><?php echo 'Topic published by '.$row['topic_creator'].' - ( '.$row['topic_date'].' )'.'';?><br><br></td></tr>
                <tr><td><?php $row['reply_user'].' Replied with: ';?><br></td></tr>
                <tr><td><?php echo $row['reply_text'].'<br><br><i>Published:  '.$row['reply_date'].' by    '.$row['reply_user'].'</i>';?></td></tr>




            <?php

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>

                <tr><td><?php $row['reply_user'].' Replied with: ';?><br></td></tr>
                <tr><td><?php echo $row['reply_text'].'<br><br><i>Published:  '.$row['reply_date'].' by    '.$row['reply_user'].'</i>';?></td></tr>


            <?php   
            }
?>
            </table>








        <?php

        }elseif (isset($_GET['cat'])){
        // Show topics in that category


        $querytopic = "SELECT topic_id, topic_title,topic_description, topic_date, category_id FROM forum_topics WHERE category_id = '".$_GET['cat']."'";
        $result = mysql_query($querytopic) or die (mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
         if(empty($row['topic_id'])){
            echo "No topics have been posted in this category, be the first to submit a topic using form below."; ?>
        <table id="categorytable">
                <tr><td><?php echo '<a href="forum.php?topic='.$row['topic_id'].'&cat='.$row['category_id'].'"><b>'.$row['topic_title'].'</b></a>';?></td></tr>
                <tr><td><?php echo $row['topic_description'];?><br><br></td></tr>
                <tr><td><?php echo "<b>Date Posted:</b>   ".$row['topic_date'];?><br><br></td></tr>
            <?php

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
                    <tr><td><?php echo '<a href="forum.php?topic='.$row['topic_id'].'&cat='.$row['category_id'].'"><br>'.$row['topic_title'].'</b></a>';?></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><?php echo $row['topic_description'];?><br><br></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><?php echo "<b>Date Posted:</b>   ".$row['topic_date'];?><br><br></td></tr>


            <?php   
            }} ?></table><?php
                if($_SESSION['loggedin'] === true){
                    $userid = $_SESSION['id'];
                    $catid = $_GET['cat'];

                    ?>

            <br>
            <form method="post" action="topic_process.php" id="topicform">
                <h3>Add New Topic</h3>
            <input type="hidden" id="catid" name="catid"  value=<?php echo $catid?> > 
            <input type="hidden" id="userid"    name="userid"  value=<?php echo $userid ?>>  
            <label for="topictitle">Topic Title:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
            <textarea rows="2" cols="80"  id="topictitle" name="topictitle"  required ></textarea>
                <br><br>
            <label for="topicdescription">Topic Description:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
            <textarea  rows="10" cols="80" id="topicdescription" name="topicdescription"   required ></textarea>
            <input type= "hidden" id="topicdate" name="topicdate" value=<?php echo ''.date('Y-m-d').'' ?>>

                <br><br>
                <input type="submit" name="topicsubmit" id="topicsubmit" value="Create Topic">


            </form>

<?php
                }
?>



        <?php   
        }else{ 
        //Just display the list of categories
        $querycategory = "SELECT category_id, category_title,category_description FROM forum_category";
        $result = mysql_query($querycategory) or die (mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); ?>

        <table id="categorytable">
                <tr><td><?php echo '<a href="forum.php?cat='.$row['category_id'].'">'.$row['category_title'].'</a>';?></td></tr>
                <tr><td><?php echo $row['category_description'];?><br><br></td></tr>
            <?php

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
                    <tr><td><?php echo '<a href="forum.php?cat='.$row['category_id'].'">'.$row['category_title'].'</a>';?></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><?php echo $row['category_description'];?><br><br></td></tr>


            <?php   
            }
                ?>
            </table>
<?php   }


 ?>

</div>
```

and here is the process page

```
session_start();
include "includes/connection.php";

echo $_POST['topictitle'];
echo $_POST['topicdescription'];
echo $_POST['userid'];
echo $_POST['catid'];




$query = "INSERT INTO forum_topics
(
    category_id,
    user_id,
    topic_title,
    topic_description,
    topic_date
    )
VALUES
    (
    '".$_POST['catid']."',
    '".$_POST['userid']."',
    '".$_POST['topictitle']."',
    '".$_POST['topicdescription']."',
    '".$_POST['topicdate']."'
    )";     
mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
header('Location: /TEST/forum.php?'.$_POST['catid'].'');


?>
```

I am also struggling to record the topic_date as today's date I tried date('Y-m-d') for 2015-04-28 but it saved as 00-00-00.

I know its a lot of code to read but I'm really stuck and don't want to miss anything, also I know mysql_functions are deprecated but have been asked to use them by uni.

Im using PHPmyadmin as the database, which I know is rubbish!
Thanks

EDIT: I have set up the page so It displays all the topics stored in the database (topic_title, topic_description, user_id, topic_date). before I add a new topic to the database this works fine but afterwards all the topics including the new one disappear leaving just the form on the page. All the records still exist on the database and deleting the new record brings back all the topics displayed on the page.

Comment: Can you please expand upon "it prevents itself and the previous topics from being displayed." what do you actually observe happening? What do you expect to observe instead? Imagine you're talking to somebody that has never seen or heard of your site and doesn't know what it does... because that's us :)

Comment: Sorry my bad, basically before i use the form to add a new topic. The site displays all the topics (titles,topic_description, user creator and date posted) in a neat table, however after I add a new topic using the form, no topics are displayed on the webpage (only the form is displayed). All the records still exist in the database though

Comment: (1) phpMyAdmin is not a database, MySQL is. phpMyAdmin has nothing to do with the code you posted. (2) you may have to use `mysql_` due to your uni, but at least sanitize your data. (3) if your `topic_date` is a date column, their is no way it would save as `00-00-00`, as it would be `0000-00-00`. Instead of trying to build your own date, just use MySQL's `NOW()` to populate the field. (4) it looks like you are missing `cat=` in your location `header('Location: /TEST/forum.php?cat='.$_POST['catid'].'')`

Comment: The topic_date is set to date and I changed the insert value to NOW() and still got 00-00-00 so not sure where the problem lays there. The cat = think worked so thank you but the main issue I'm trying to solve is why these records are preventing my topics from being displayed like they do when the new records don't exist